# Split a 2D array of values to X and y datasets

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following np.ndarray:

```
>>> arr
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

I would like to split it to X and y where each array is coordinates and values, respectively. So far I managed to solve this using [np.ndenumerate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html):

```py
>>> X, y = zip(*np.ndenumerate(arr))
>>> X 
((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1))
>>> y
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I'm wondering if there's a more idiomatic and faster way to achieve it, since the arrays I'm actually dealing with have millions of values.

I need the X and y array to pass them to a [sklearn classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor.html) later. The formats above seemed the most natural for me, but perhaps there's a better way I can pass them to the `fit` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshaping `arr` to `y` is easy, you can achieve it by `y = arr.flatten()`. I suggest treating generating `X` as a separate task.

Let's assume that your dataset is of shape `NxM`. In our benchmark we set `N` to 500 and `M` to 1000.

```
N = 500
M = 1000
arr = np.random.randn(N, M)
```

Then by using `np.mgrid` and transforming indices you can get the result as:

```
np.mgrid[:N, :M].transpose(1, 2, 0).reshape(-1, 2)
```

Benchmarks:

```
%timeit np.mgrid[:N, :M].transpose(1, 2, 0).reshape(-1, 2)
# 3.11 ms ± 35.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit zip(*np.ndenumerate(arr))
# 235 ms ± 1.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

In your case you can unpack and get `N` and `M` by:

```
N, M = arr.shape
```

and then:

```
X = np.mgrid[:N, :M].transpose(1, 2, 0).reshape(-1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.where` with `numpy.ravel()`:

```
import numpy as np

def ndenumerate(np_array):
    return list(zip(*np.where(np_array+1))), np_array.ravel()

arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000,1000))

X_new, y_new = ndenumerate(arr)
X,y = zip(*np.ndenumerate(arr))
```

Output (validation):

```
all(i1 == i2 for i1, i2 in zip(X, X_new))
# True
all(y == y_new)
# True
```

Benchmark (about 3x faster):

```
%timeit ndenumerate(arr)
# 234 ms ± 20.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit zip(*np.ndenumerate(arr))
# 877 ms ± 91.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I marked the other answer as accepted as it's two orders of magnitude faster than this one. Thank you, though!